# The placement of static global and global variables with the same identifier

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I'm learning some basics about linking and encountered the following code.

#### file: f1.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

static int foo;

int main() {
    int *bar();
    printf("%ld\n", bar() - &foo);
    return 0;
}
```

#### file: f2.c

```c
int foo = 0;
int *bar() {
    return &foo;
}
```

Then a problem asks me whether this statement is correct: No matter how the program is compiled, linked or run, the output of it must be a constant (with respect to multiple runs) and it is non-zero.

I think this is correct. Although there are two definitions of `foo`, one of them is declared with `static`, so it shadows the global `foo`, thus the linker will not pick only one `foo`. Since the relative position of variables should be fixed when run (although the absolute addresses can vary), the output must be a constant.

I experimented with the code and on `gcc 7.5.0` with `gcc f1.c f2.c -o test && ./test` it would always output `1` (but if I remove the `static`, it would output `0`). But the answer says that the statement above is wrong. I wonder why. Are there any mistakes in my understanding?

A result of `objdump` follows. Both `foo`s go to `.bss`.
[image]

**Context.** This is a problem related to the linking chapter of Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective by Randal E. Bryant and David R. O'Hallaron. But it does not come from the book.

**Update.** OK now I've found out the reason. If we swap the order and compile as `gcc f2.c f1.c -o test && ./test`, it will output `-1`. Quite a boring problem...

Comment: It should technically be undefined behavior to do the subtraction unless you first cast the pointer to a suitable integer type, but practically (or when doing the subtraction in uintptr_t), it should be true as long as the files end up compiled into the same binary (if they end up in different shared libs, the relative position could change between multiple runs).

Comment: Even with the appropriate cast, see https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p9. The two addresses do not satisfy the constraint, so the behavior is not well defined.

Comment: If you remove the `static` it shouldn't compile.

Comment: @PSkocik In this instance, it's okay for the reasons you mentioned. It's okay to subtract pointers (always) as long as you don't expect meaningful results from the subtraction. Doing `!=` or `==` instead of `-` might be more palatable. Or, just printing with `%p`

Comment: `Then a problem asks me` Can you share a bit more about the context of the problem? Is this problem "theoretical" and related to C programming - i.e. the answer is intended to be undefined behavior, ergo the compiler _is allowed_ to generate code that outputs different stuff every run? Or is the problem is practical related to some specific environment, like specifically Linux? The dynamic loader could theoretically allocate segments from each file in different order (is this possible?). It's my only idea.

Comment: In f1.c we have `static int foo;` which goes to the `.bss` section. In f2.c, we have `int foo = 0;` which goes to the `.data` section. So, they're definitely going to be different because they go into different load segments. A better example/test would be to leave off the initializer in f2.c so that it, too, goes to `.bss`. The address will still be different but it should be closer.

Comment: @KamilCuk It's a problem when learning the book CSAPP so we can say it defaults to Linux (I thought this problem was intended for the placement and shadowing rules). I think the loader is not very relevant since both ```foo```s will be inside the ```.bss``` segment in the final executable.

Comment: @CraigEstey No. Data initialized to 0 will go to ```.bss```. (I'll post a result of ```objdump``` now.)

Comment: @KamilCuk OK. But this is not a problem from the book.

Comment: Re “it shadows the global `foo`”: C does not have any global name space (except for keywords like `int`) or scope. Its largest scope is file scope, and the two `foo` are in separate files (translation units). Making names refer to the same object is done by linkage, and the `static int foo;` has internal linkage, so it is not seen when the linker is resolving external linkage.

Comment: Does “No matter how the program is compiled, linked or run, the output of it must be a constant (with respect to multiple runs) and it is non-zero.” mean that the output might vary if the program is linked differently? E.g., given my particular system, `cc -o f f1.c f2.c && ./f` prints “1” whereas `cc -o f f2.c f1.c && ./f` prints “-1”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Exactly. See the updates of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed the static variable `foo` in the **f1.c** module is a different object from the global `foo` in the **f2.c** module referred to by the `bar()` function. Hence the output should be non zero.

Note however that subtracting 2 pointers that do not point to the same array or one past the end of the same array is meaningless, hence the difference might be `0` even for different objects.  This may happen even as `&foo == bar()` would be non `0` because the objects are different.  This behavior was common place in 16-bit segmented systems using the large model where subtracting pointers only affected the offset portion of the pointers whereas comparing them for equality compared both the segment and the offset parts. Modern systems have a more regular architecture where everything is in the same address space. Just be aware that not every system is a linux PC.

Furthermore, the `printf` conversion format `%ld` expects a value of type `long` whereas you pass a value of type `ptrdiff_t` which may be a different type (namely 64-bit `long long` on Windows 64-bit targets for example, which is different from 32-bit long there). Either use the correct format `%td` or cast the argument as `(long)(bar() - &foo)`.

Finally, nothing in the C language guarantees that the difference between the addresses of global objects be constant across different runs of the same program. Many modern systems perform address space randomisation to lessen the risk of successful attacks, leading to different addresses for stack objects and/or static data in successive runs of the same executable.

Answer (score 1):

Abstracting from the wring printf formats and pointer arithmetic problems `static` global variable from one compilation unit will be different than `static` and `non-static` variables having that same name in other compilation units.

to correctly see the difference in `char`s you should cast both to char pointer and use `%td` format which will print `ptrdiff_t` type. If your platform does not support it, cast the result to `long long int`

```
int main() {
    int *bar();
    printf("%td\n", (char *)bar() - (char *)&foo);
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
printf("%lld\n", (long long)((char *)bar() - (char *)&foo));
```

If you want to store this difference in the variable use `ptrdiff_t` type:

```
ptrdiff_t diff = (char *)bar() - (char *)&foo;
```

Comment: Re “to correctly”: To correctly implement the author’s intent, one should not subtract the pointers, because the behavior when pointers to objects not inside the same aggregate are subtracted is not defined by the C standard. One could first convert to `uintptr_t` and then subtract, although then the results are still implementation-defined and might produce different integers for the “same” address in different runs, and we are not guaranteed (by the C standard) the same integer difference even for addresses that are the same offset from each other.